# change the pivot of an imageView

Tags: android, position, imageview

In android the position of an ImageView is determined by the top left side of the image. i wanted to know if it's possible to change that. so that the image will be drawn from the the center of the lower side of the image. 
i know you can do it in other programming languages.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a bit of math.

```
int centerX = ImageView.getWidth / 2;
int centerY = ImageView.getHeight / 2;

ImageView.setX(x+centerX);
ImageView.setY(x+centerY);
```

You can finagle that into a method, or create a new class extending ImageView if you want to make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setPivotX(imageView.getWidth()/2);    
imageView.setPivotY(imageView.getHeight());
```

you may try also:

```
imageView.setPivotX(imageView.getMeasuredWidth()/2);    
imageView.setPivotY(imageView.getMeasuredHeight());
```